# How to access an IP Camera in chrome

Tags: ip, port, router, ip-camera

I have 2 different IP cameras. When I use sign in to my NEW router I can see one cameras IP address there:
192.168.1.100

I also have another IP camera that I long time before found in ipconfig in cmd on the below address
192.168.1.4
I could then before enter only the 192.168.1.4 in chrome browser and it logged in to the IP Cameras settings page where I could change its port to 1024 so I now can enter in Chrome: 192.168.1.4:1024 so log in to the camera. However this IP camera 192.168.1.4 is not shown in the devices on my NEW router.

The problem is:
When I enter 192.168.1.100 in chrome, I only get a "Website can't be reached" I also can't find out what port this IP camera use. I have used WireShark and other port sniffer tools.

Any idéa of what to do in order to get to the cameras setting in chrome or get a connection with this camera. Finding out the port to 192.168.1.100 should be one factor I beleive?

*(If I use "Onvif Device Manager" this software automatically find the camera and shows the feed which means that something is working. But it doesn't provide what http port that it is found on)*

Comment: Have you tried to reset the camera by holding the power button, then reconfigure it as if it was a new camera?

Have you also tried to install the latest firmware update on your cameras?

What is the brand of your camera?

Comment: In the Onvif Device Manager, what's the Address written in the device list (on the left side of the app) when you are able to see the video feed?

Comment: In the Onvif Device Manager, when you click on the tab of your camera, there is supposed to be a list of link you can click on. For my part, there's `Identification`, `Time settings`, `Maintenance`, ... Is there any link like `Network settings`? If so, go under this tab/link and look for the `HTTP port` to see if it's enabled. If it is, try entering the IP of your camera followed by `:` and your port. ex: `192.168.1.123:80`.